# Enter passphrase for key for second user's SHA

Tags: windows, git-bash

This is kind of a long story. I received a laptop from work and installed and configured Gitbash. It was later decided that the laptop should be given to my colleague, who made his own user account and installed gitbash. Finally, it was decided that I should keep my old laptop.

The problem is now when I try to commit a file, it asks me enter passphrase for key [path to .ssh/id_rsa] for my colleagues account.

Is there a way I can get Gitbash to commit files using my profile and not my colleague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should ask for your colleague's key only if `%HOME%` is set to your colleague `%USERPROFILE%`.

Make sure `%HOME%` is set to your own `%USERPROFILE%` folder (`C:\Users\yourLogin`), and your ssh key will be selected.

Comment: Brilliant! I was expecting a much more complicated answer than that :)